# Cannot populate list of SQL views or tables in Azure Data Share setup

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-share

I am attempting to share an SQL view via Azure Data Share.  I have set up the data share, created a share to send, and am attempting to add a dataset.  I am logged into Azure Portal as me@example.com.  I am also connected to the database (an Azure SQL DB) in SSMS as me@example.com.  I do the following:

1. Select "Add datasets"
2. Select "Azure SQL Database"
3. Select the resource group
4. Select the SQL server

I got the the message about setting up permissions (the create user and exec sp_addrolemember db_datareader query), which I did successfully in SSMS.  So, next I select the data, which was found successfully, and select "Next".  This is where the problem starts.

I am given the options for Tables and Views.  However, neither is populated.  I can see all the tables and views in SSMS, including the view I created.  However, when I select, say, "View" from the 2 options, it finds nothing and says, "No results to show".

This is mystifying.  I clearly have access and permissions, yet it won't even populate the list of views.  Any suggestions what might be causing this?  This is my first Azure Data Share, and I could easily have missed something, but it seems like it should have everything that it needs for this operation.

Here are my assumptions:

- It is using my Azure Portal login credentials to authorize access to populate the list.
- The fact that I can see the tables and views in the SSMS Object Explorer implies sufficient permission to see the same in Azure Portal.
- Since this data share and the database are in the same resource group, no firewall configuration is needed.

Comment: have you explicitly assigned SQL DB Contributor or 
SQL Server Contributor role to yourself on your Azure sql server ? It is not assigned by default even if you have created the sql server yourself

Comment: Hi Andrew, I experienced the same few days back while trying to repro your ask, but now when I try the exact same procedure, I am able to list the tables and views. Can you try and confirm now

Comment: Yep, it works now.  Is this what MS likes to call a "transient issue"? :-)